# list numbers 1 to n in function - SML

Tags: sml, ml

I need to create a function in sml that takes a single number and returns a list of all the numbers that are prime below it. I can do that but I dont know how to create a list so i can use to see if 1 is prime then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5 and so on.

Basicly i need a way to generate a list inside of an SML function and that list has the numbers from 2 to n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [List.tabulate](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG%3aLIST.tabulate%3aVAL) function will populate a list for you. Here's an example, giving you the numbers `[2..n]`:

```
List.tabulate(n-1, fn x => x+2);
```

Comment: does that return a list or does it store it somewhere, im new to functional programming. (it returns it apparently)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that we can not use external libraries for this so I actually was able to come up with a solution of my own. It does the numbers from `start` to up to, but not including, `ending`

```
fun createList(start:int, ending:int) = if(start = ending) then
                       []
                    else
                       start::createList(start + 1, ending);
```

Comment: long time ago, but figured it would be nice to add as a comment, you wouldn't even have to tell it that start and end are ints. That is the beauty of type inference. ML would see that you are adding 1 (an int) to start, and since the type of + is int * int -> int, it would reason that start is an int. You then perform an equality check between start and ending, so ending must be an int too! Pretty sweet no?

Comment: `if (start = ending) then [ending]`... works for me.